# Which step was wrong. Please help on this question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity

I choose step 5 as wrong in this question, but since I failed the test. I need the right answer
Edit: I know x=3 is not possible but still want to know exactly which step is wrong?
**This is the question:**
[image: Question]

Comment: Hint:  Note that $x=3$ is not possible, since it would make the initial expression singular.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So Step 5 is wrong, just confirming.

Comment: Also, the first step is not valid unless we impose the restrictions that $x \neq -1$ and $x \neq 3$.

Comment: I don't know what the official answer should be.  What I would say is that Robert did nothing at all wrong, but that there should have been a step $6$ during which Robert checked that one of the two solutions was not possible.  Or one could say that Step $1$ ought to have included the clause $x\neq -1,3$.

Comment: Hmm, I thanks @N.F.Taussig, I think you are right.

Comment: Thanks, @lulu I was thinking the same but there is not step 6

Comment: The problem is that the "solution" is too terse.  If one understands that each step is a one directional implication then there is nothing wrong except for the missing step $6$.  If one understands that each step is meant to be "iff" then Step $1$ is wrong.

Comment: It's either step 1) or nothing wrong.  $x=3$ or $x=-3$ is a correct but incomplete conclusion. After all $x$ is $-3$ so it *is* true that $x=3$ or $x=-3$. ($x=-3$ or $x=27$ or $x\in \mathbb Z$ would also be true but incomplete conclusions). If getting a solution that is too broad an error then step 1) would need to be $x-3+x^2-x-2=4$ *and* $(x+1)(x-3)\ne 0$. (Step 2, could be  $x^2-5=4$ and $x\ne -1;x\ne 3$ and 4) $(x-3)(x+3)=0$ but $x\ne 3;x\ne-1$)

Comment: @lulu: I just saw this, and I totally agree with all aspects of your comment that begins with "The problem is that". This is a type of item that is very difficult to make reasonably defensible against a challenge by a knowledgeable test taker, perhaps one with an axe to grind against the test itself, without seriously compromising the intended verbal/logical complexity of the question. FYI, see the parenthetical sentence in my comment [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17727/acceptability-of-creative-questions-in-assessments#comment47265_17727) directed to Rusty Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step $1$ is not correct.

You should write

step 1
$$(x-3+x^2-x-2=4)  \wedge  x\ne -1 \wedge x\ne 3$$

step 2

$$x^2-5=4 \wedge  x\ne -1 \wedge x\ne 3$$
step 3

$$x^2-9=0 \wedge x\ne -1 \wedge x\ne 3$$

step 4

$$(x+3)(x-3)=0 \wedge x\ne -1 \wedge x\ne 3$$

step 5
$$(x=3 \vee x=-3) \wedge x\notin \{-1,3\} $$

step 6
$$x=-3$$